# How to transfer github remote in Xcode

Tags: xcode, github, git-remote

There was an error in my original project so I downloaded a past version of it through GitHub. I added an existing remote and used the github address for the location. When I commit and push, it pushes the files on "main" instead of "master" (the original one). How can I make it push onto the master branch?

Comment: What is the swift tag for?

Comment: Select the master branch at first?

Comment: I can't choose any branch it just automatically goes to main. Is there a way to select a branch?